# Dynamically add and remove content in GUI form

Tags: arrays, wpf, winforms, powershell

I am trying to create in PowerShell a GUI window with dynamic content. I need to:

- create a window with a random count of buttons (or other clickable items)
- after a click button and related text label will be removed from the window

IMPORTANT: I cannot use a list or datagrid.

I have the following code but it still returns only last item value.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,400)

$Array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Array.add('AAA')
$Array.add('BBB')
$Array.add('CCC')
$Array.add('DDD')

foreach ($item in $Array) {
  New-Variable -Force -Name "button$membershipCount" -Value (New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button)
  $thisButton = Get-Variable -ValueOnly -Include "button$membershipCount"
  $thisButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(175,(35+26*$membershipCount))
  $thisButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,23)
  $thisButton.Text = $item
  $thisButton.Add_Click({(Write-Host $thisButton.Text | Out-Null)})

  $form.Controls.Add($CHANGEButton)
}
```

I also tried `Invoke-Expression`, but it doesn't return expected results:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "`$thisButton.Add_Click({`$x=`"$($item)`";`write-host $x})"
```

Or any better idea how can I get details which button was clicked since the number of buttons is random?

Comment: Shouldn't the last statement in the `foreach` loop be `$form.Controls.Add($thisButton)` and not `$form.Controls.Add($CHANGEButton)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the scriptblock inside `add_Click()` now contains a reference to `$thisbutton`, which at runtime will have been replaced with the last value in the foreach loop - this is expected behavior.

You can do 1 of 2 things here.

#### 1. Capture the `$thisButton.Text` (or `$item`) value in a closure:

```
# Piping to Out-Null has zero effect here, just remove it 
$thisButton.Add_Click({Write-Host $thisButton.Text}.GetNewClosure())
```

#### 2. Use the event arguments to determine which button was clicked at runtime:

```
$thisButton.Add_Click({param($Sender,$EventArgs) Write-Host $Sender.Text})
```